# How to capture test is failed or passed in a Test and write in Excel sheet

Tags: selenium, junit, apache-poi

I am new to Apache poi. I have a test which has many assert check, also test parameters are taken using apache poi plugins. Now if any of the assert in a test failed i wat to write it in another excel sheet which has same test parameters but with test result. Below is my code -

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class testClass {

    ExcelUtils ex = new ExcelUtils(path);

    @Parameters
    public static String[][] data() {
        String[][] tableArray = ex.getTableArray("sheet1");
        return (tableArray);
    }

    private final String TN;
    private final String Pro;

    public testClass(String TN, String Pro) {
        this.TN = TN;
        this.Pro = Pro;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.Println(TN);
        System.out.println(Pro);
        //Also Code which has lots of assert operations
    }

    @Rule
    public TestRule listen = new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            //I need help to write code to capturetest result
        }
    };
}
```

I am using junit test framework

Comment: Using a test watcher is already the right approach. The `Throwable` object contains the information about the failing test. You now need the POI code that writes to the excel file. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure how to copy the existing excel file with parameters and find the cell and write the pass or fail result